# got a row's all information from a table in SQL

Tags: sql

Given the table below:

```
ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
3           Teddy       23          Norway      20000.0
4           Mark        25          Rich-Mond   65000.0
5           David       27          Texas       85000.0
6           Kim         22          South-Hall  45000.0
7           James       24          Houston     10000.0
```

How to get all the information of a specific row?

For example I want it to show:

```
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
```

what should I use in SQL?

Comment: select * from [that table] where Id=1

Comment: You shouldn't use select * on a production query though. You should always name the columns you want. If you want all of them, then list all of them. Select ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `select *`?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments, you'd have to explicitly select all the fields you're interested in:

```
SELECT name, age, address, salary FROM mytable WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: is there a way to hide the 'key' and just show the values in that row?

Comment: @Liquid you'd have to explicitly select them - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you know the id use `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary 
FROM c_table 
WHERE Id=1
```

When you don't know the id You can use `TOP`/ `LIMIT`/ `ROWNUM` Clauses based on database

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary 
FROM c_table;
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary 
FROM c_table 
LIMIT 1;
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age, Address, Salary 
FROM c_table 
WHERE ROWNUM <=1;
```